# Extracting maximum values of variable that within range

Tags: r, dataframe, range, max, intervals

I have a data frame that contains a series of variables, as so:

```
Name <- paste(letters[1:26])
Time1 <- runif(n = 26, min = 0,max= 500)
Time2 <- runif(n =26, min = 0,max= 500)
V4 <- runif(n = 26, min = 0, max = 1000 )
df <- data.frame(Name, Time1,Time2, V4)
```

I want to find maximum values of V4 that exist within specific ranges of `Time1` and `Time2`. For example, I would check all the data that exists with `Time 1 >=0` and `Time2 <= 10`, `Time1 >= 10` and `Time2 <= 20`, `Time1 >=20` and `Time2 <=30` ... etc., and find the maximum value of `V4` and it's corresponding `Name` within those ranges.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- For each pair of time bounds, sub-select the dataframe using e.g.

  `df2 <- df[(df$Time1>=0) & (df$Time1<10), ]`
- combine that with `which.max` and column selection to get the row index:

  `idx <- which.max(df2$V4)`
- `df2[idx, 'Name']` should give you what you want.

Comment: @42-: Right, sorry, fixed.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to do this more efficiently if there are many intervals? In the example I just listed a couple, but in my actual data there are ~100 intervals I want to check the maximums for, which would be time consuming to type out individually.

Comment: I would make a function like `get_max_interval <- function(a, b) { ...}`, where `a` and `b` replace the `0` and `10` in the code above. Then make a list/matrix of a,b pairs, and use an `apply` function over that list.